# AWS ECS Task fails with: CannotPullContainerError

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs

I'm working with aws ecs service for the first time and running into some permission issues. I'm using terraform to create a task definition and service definition.

My task definitions json config:

```
  [
      {
          "dnsSearchDomains": null,
          "logConfiguration": null,
          "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 0,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
          ],
          "entryPoint": [
            "httpd",
            "-DFOREGROUND"
          ],
          "command": null,
          "linuxParameters": null,
          "cpu": 0,
          "resourceRequirements": null,
          "ulimits": null,
          "dnsServers": null,
          "mountPoints": [],
          "workingDirectory": null,
          "secrets": [
            ...my_secrets..
          ],
          "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
          "memory": 350,
          "memoryReservation": null,
          "volumesFrom": [],
          "stopTimeout": null,
          "image": "${api_image}",
          "startTimeout": null,
          "dependsOn": null,
          "disableNetworking": null,
          "interactive": null,
          "healthCheck": null,
          "essential": true,
          "links": null,
          "hostname": null,
          "extraHosts": null,
          "pseudoTerminal": null,
          "user": null,
          "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
          "dockerLabels": null,
          "systemControls": null,
          "privileged": null,
          "name": "myApp"
        }
    ]
```

The IAM role I create for the task definition iam_role.tf:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "api" {
  name = "api-${var.environment}"
  assume_role_policy = "${file("../../policies/iam_ecs_role.json")}"

  tags = {
      terraform = true
  }
}

# Attach SSM read only policy to read from param store.
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach-ssm" {
    role        = "${aws_iam_role.api.name}"
    policy_arn  = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMReadOnlyAccess"
}

# Attach policy to allow read and push from ECR. 
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach-ecs-task" {
    role        = "${aws_iam_role.api.name}"
    policy_arn  = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

# Attach policy to allow access to KSM to decrypt ssm values. 
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach-ksm" {
    role        = "${aws_iam_role.api.name}"
    policy_arn  = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach-admin" {
    role        = "${aws_iam_role.api.name}"
    policy_arn  = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"
}
```

And the policy json file from the previous role resource:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": [
              "ecs.amazonaws.com", 
              "ec2.amazonaws.com",
              "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            ]
        },
        "Effect": "Allow"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So the role I have has the following policy:
[image]

The issue I'm having is when I launch the deploy the service to the cluster I get the following error in in the tasks:

> CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for xxxxxxxxx.xxx.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

I can't seem to figure out why the task is having trouble pulling from ecr. The instance the container is launched on exists in a public subnet and has a public ip so it definitely has access to the internet. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you also need to add ECR access to your EC2 instance role

Comment: Where do you configure the ECS task to pull from `xxxxxxxx.xxx.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-image`? Based on the error message it seems like you might just not be using the correct url for the repository.

Comment: The url should be fine. I'm using terraform and It's a string stored as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should get permission of ECR in `ECS Task Execution IAM Role`.

Here is a example policy of task execution role.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

> See :
>
> Here's [AWS Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html) about ecs task execution role